# Is the location field missing on Google+ Search API results?

Tags: search, location, google-plus

We have a test public post, with public location sharing on.  It is here:

https://plus.google.com/117438835632597579589/posts/CrqqvQf4kLx

This has a location tagged in the message, which is shown in the browser.

When we call the API there is no location field shown as the docs suggest there will be (https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities).  This is the JSON that is returned:

```
{u'access': {u'kind': u'plus#acl'},
 u'actor': {u'displayName': u'Stuart Battersby',
        u'id': u'117438835632597579589',
        u'image': {u'url': u'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-D3bdMxwKXm4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADn8/_1qBDTPoAcU/photo.jpg?sz=50'},
        u'url': u'https://plus.google.com/117438835632597579589'},
 u'etag': u'"G6azxXlXkwWbV_x-oI3I6szOTWs/ZXO3RDThBxUUobZJEK2PL2qeQBI"',
 u'id': u'z124whmabknyw1wua230stwiyn2wenk2d',
 u'kind': u'plus#activity',
 u'object': {u'content': u'Checking out the Google+ app for android...',
         u'objectType': u'note',
         u'plusoners': {u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z124whmabknyw1wua230stwiyn2wenk2d/people/plusoners',
                        u'totalItems': 1},
         u'replies': {u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z124whmabknyw1wua230stwiyn2wenk2d/comments',
                      u'totalItems': 0},
         u'resharers': {u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z124whmabknyw1wua230stwiyn2wenk2d/people/resharers',
                        u'totalItems': 0},
         u'url': u'https://plus.google.com/117438835632597579589/posts/CrqqvQf4kLx'},
 u'provider': {u'title': u'Mobile'},
 u'published': u'2013-06-28T08:56:53.110Z',
 u'title': u'Checking out the Google+ app for android...',
 u'updated': u'2013-06-28T08:56:53.110Z',
 u'url': u'https://plus.google.com/117438835632597579589/posts/CrqqvQf4kLx',
 u'verb': u'post'}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the location information in the Google+ API has been broken for quite a while already... Here's an issue you can star: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=393

Comment: Gah, shame. Thanks, have stared and closed this question.  Hope it gets fixed soon.